# Round brackets in Chicago style footnote citations

Tags: formatting, footnotes, chicago-style, biblatex-chicago

I'm looking for a way to get rid of round brackets in footnotes (around publishers) which are automatically generated using the *biblatex-chicago* package.

Any suggestions how this could be done? I would like the book citation to appear without brackets, pretty much as it would in the bibliography (here: "John L. Austin. How to do things with words. Cambridge, Mass.: Harvard
University Press, 1975.").

```
\documentclass[12pt,pagesize=auto, titlepage=on]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[notes,backend=biber,doi=false,isbn=false,url=false]{biblatex-chicago}
\bibliography{literatur.bib}     
\begin{document}

Citation.\autocite{austin1975things}     
\end{document}
```

[image: Example of Problem]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to do this, you need to adjust the macro that prints the `location`, `publisher`, and `year`. For `@book` entry types this is the macro `cpubl+loc+year`.

Depending on the entry types you use, you may have to adjust other macros as well to make things consistent. You can find the macros you need in `chicago-notes.cbx`.

In this MWE, I just comment out the part that includes parentheses so you can see what is going on. You also need to replace the `\setunit{\addspace}` with `\newcunit` to ensure that a comma is inserted before the `location`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[notes,backend=biber,doi=false,isbn=false,url=false]{biblatex-chicago}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples.bib}
\renewbibmacro*{cpubl+loc+year}{% Revised for reprint
  \ifboolexpr{%
    test {\iflistundef{location}}%
    and
    test {\iflistundef{publisher}}%
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{year}}%
    and
    not togl {cms@reprint}%
  }%
  {}%
  {%\setunit{\addspace}% <- replace with \newcunit
   \newcunit
   %\printtext[parens]{% <- remove parentheses
      \usebibmacro{origpubl+loc+year}%{cmsorigdate}%\printfield{origyear}%
      \setunit*{\addsemicolon\addspace}%
      \ifboolexpr{%
        togl {cms@reprint}%
        and
        not test{\ifentrytype{video}}%
      }%
      {\bibsstring{reprint}%
        \newcunit}%
      {}%
      \printlist{location}%
      \iflistundef{publisher}%
      {\setunit*{\addspace}}%
      {\setunit*{\addcolon\addspace}}%
      \printlist{publisher}%
      \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
      \usebibmacro{date}%
    %} <- remove parentheses
}}%

\begin{document}
\null\vfill
Filler text \autocite{kullback}.
\end{document}
```

[image]